# Installing FreeBSD from a USB

Tags: freebsd

so I have a lenovo laptop i7 with two hard drives. My ssd which boots windows on UEFI, and my second a hybrid hard drive. I created two partitions on my second hard drive. One for storage for my windows drive, and the other(500gb), where I would like to install FreeBSD. I made the two partitions in windows, and burned the FreeBSD memstick file onto a usb and booted. When I get to the installation menu, it does not show all my disks under manual installation. It only shows my USB as a partition, which is 8gb. If I try to do the guided installation and select from partitions. I get an error that says out of index 5.

Any Ideas why this is occurring?

Comment: https://wiki.freebsd.org/UEFI

Comment: I dont have a problem booting from a usb with freeBSD. The issue is when it asks me what partition to install it on; it does not show all my disks. It just shows da0 which is my usb. Only freeBSD does this. The other *nix distros detect my other partitions...

Comment: check the bios settings, probably this can help: https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/installation-does-not-detect-hard-disk.31981/

Comment: Depending on the brand, the hybrid drive could also be a problem. Some of them are implemented as two drives and the caching is done in software.  So it looks like a small ssd and hard drive.  The partition table might look corrupt to FreeBSD. 

Try going to a shell and running gpt show and see what it does.